# Only few mails getting delivered using sp_send_dbmail in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am extracting the recipient list from a column in a table and I am running the stored procedure `sp_send_dbmail` to send the emails to these recipients.

There are a total of around 200 recipients.

Ironically only few of the mails are delivered even though the message that I am getting is **Mail queued**. The database mail is correctly configured and I am using the `Public` database profile.

When I check the `msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems` table, as expected value in `sent_status` column is 1 for the recipients for whom the mail is delivered and for rest of them the value is either 0 or 2.

I am completely sure that the recipient list is 100% correct. Do we have any workaround to resolve this issue?

Below is the code that I am running:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_dataRefreshNotification]  
AS  
BEGIN  
DECLARE @ToMail VARCHAR(20)  
DECLARE @Body1 VARCHAR(MAX) =   
'Dear User,  
Data has been refreshed.  
Regards,  
IT Support Team  

Note: This is an auto generated e-mail, please do not reply this mail. '      

SELECT DISTINCT RecipientAddress FROM dbo.RecipientAddressList  
OPEN notification_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM notification_cursor  
INTO @ToMail  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
@profile_name  ='aaaa',    
@Recipients = @Tomail,  
@Subject = 'Required Data',      
@Body = @Body1  
FETCH NEXT FROM notification_cursor  
INTO @ToMail  
END  
CLOSE notification_cursor  
DEALLOCATE notification_cursor  
END
```

Comment: Can you show some code that you are using to send emails?

Comment: @M.Ali: I have added the code in my question.

Comment: Run SQL Server Management Studio and view log of Database Mail component - you have all information about real problems with sending your mails. Let us know what are errors there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Wait for Delay function which will break each instance of your cursor.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_dataRefreshNotification]  
AS  
BEGIN  
DECLARE @ToMail VARCHAR(20)  
DECLARE @Body1 VARCHAR(MAX) =   
'Dear User,  
Data has been refreshed.  
Regards,  
IT Support Team  

Note: This is an auto generated e-mail, please do not reply this mail. '      

SELECT DISTINCT RecipientAddress FROM dbo.RecipientAddressList  
OPEN notification_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM notification_cursor  
INTO @ToMail  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
Waitfor Delay '000:00:10' 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
@profile_name  ='aaaa',    
@Recipients = @Tomail,  
@Subject = 'Required Data',      
@Body = @Body1  
FETCH NEXT FROM notification_cursor  
INTO @ToMail  
END  
CLOSE notification_cursor  
DEALLOCATE notification_cursor  
END
```

Answer (score 0):

ouch you do not need a cursor here, same thing can be done using a simple select query, see below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_dataRefreshNotification]  
AS  
BEGIN  
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @ToMail VARCHAR(MAX);  
    DECLARE @Body1 VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Body1  =   'Dear User, ' + CHAR(10) + 
                'Data has been refreshed.   ' + CHAR(10) + 
                'Regards,   ' + CHAR(10) + 
                'IT Support Team   ' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + 

                'Note: This is an auto generated e-mail, please do not reply this mail.  ' + CHAR(10)    


    SELECT @ToMail = COALESCE(@ToMail+';' ,'') + RecipientAddress 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RecipientAddress 
          FROM dbo.RecipientAddressList) t

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  @profile_name  ='aaaa'
                                 ,@Recipients = @Tomail
                                 ,@Subject = 'Required Data'
                                 ,@Body = @Body1  

END
```

Comment: Following this approach will give the complete recipient list to each and every recipient which I don't want to do due to privacy constrains.

Comment: well rest of the procedure appears to be ok to me. One very important question, Are you sure no email is longer than 20 characters in length ???? your VARCHAR(20) for email variable raises suspicion.

Comment: Yes I am sure about this. I checked the recipient list multiple times and after realizing the maximum length of around 17-18 characters, I used 20 to be on safer side.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to send a separate email to each individual, then your method is good using the loop and a WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10' in the loop. But if you could send one email to all individuals, then you could concatenate these emails. Only there is a maximum of 255 characters of concatenated emails that can be in the recipient box. So you'd have to break the resulted string into pieces or 255 characters of less.